# Assign alias to group field in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark SQL, is it possible to assign an alias to the grouped field?

So for example, I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT field_b
FROM table
GROUP BY some_func(field_a) AS field_b
```

which is not supported, instead I have to do:

```
SELECT some_func(field_a) AS field_b
FROM table
GROUP BY some_func(field_a)
```

As you can see I need to call `some_func` twice which is kind of annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use some aggregation function you can either use subquery:

```sql
SELECT field_b, SOME_AGG(field_c) FROM (
  SELECT *, SOME_FUNC(field_a) field_b FROM table
) tmp GROUP BY field_b
```

or DSL:

```scala
table.groupBy(some_func($"field_a").alias("field_b"))
  .agg(some_agg($"field_c"))
```

If you don't use aggregations `distinct` clause will have the same effect:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT some_func(field_a) field_b FROM table
```

with DSL equivalent:

```scala
table.select(some_func($"field_a").alias("field_b")).distinct
```

Comment: So in the second query of my question, does spark actually call `some_func` twice for each row? And does the subquery approach perform better than my second query?